# java jlist - AbstractListModel - fireContentsChanged does not work properly

Tags: java, swing, jlist, updating

I have a simple `ListModel`, that is filterable and is used in a `JList`...

It uses the following code...

```
public class FilteredListModel extends AbstractListModel
{
private List<LineData> data = null;
private final ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public FilteredListModel()
{
}

public void setData(List<LineData> data)
{
    this.data = data;
    doFilter();
}

public void doFilter()
{
    int oldSize = indices.size();
    indices.clear();

    if (data != null)
    {
        int count = data.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            IFiltererListObject element = (IFiltererListObject) data.get(i);
            if (element.isVisible())
                indices.add(i);
        }
    }
    fireContentsChanged(this, 0, getSize() - 1);
    if (oldSize > getSize())
        fireIntervalRemoved(this, getSize(), oldSize - 1);
}

@Override
public int getSize()
{
    return indices.size();
}

@Override
public Object getElementAt(int index)
{
    return data.get(indices.get(index));
}

@Override
public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener l)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //doFilter();
}

@Override
public void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener l)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //doFilter();
}
}
```

The strange thing about it is, that it is not working, just if I click for example outside the window, the `JList` with the `ListModel` get's correctly updated...

What am I missing here?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Actually, I edited my post in the meanwhile and added the whole class... All I do is calling doFilters after updating the data... but that's not working so far...

Comment: *"added the whole class"*  An SSCCE might consist of more than one class and your code as is, is ***not an SSCCE.***  Don't get me wrong, it is **short** enough, but look at the rest of the term..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `addListDataListener` and `removeListDataListener` methods are empty. This means the `JList` can no longer attach its listener to the model. The call `fireContentsChanged` will do nothing, as the super class isn't aware of any listeners.

Either do not override those methods, or make sure you call `super.addListDataListener` as well.

Comment: sorry please can you be little bit concrete, otherwise .......hmmm I'd be use JTable, one column, without JTableHeader rather than bothering with wind in bottle

Comment: @mKorbel What do you mean with more concrete. He should either not override those methods from `AbstractListModel` or at least call the `super` method when overriding those. Now no listeners can be added to the model

Comment: never ever seen good AbstractListModel, there are a bunch small inconveniences that made things ...., see my deleted post here

Comment: actually, I realised that those methods are causing the problem... and changed my class to extending `DefaultListModel` and everything is working fine... thanks though

Answer (score 1):

@Robin please DYM???

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.MutableComboBoxModel;

//usage == new JComboBox(new SectionComboBoxModel(new ArrayList());
public class SectionComboBoxModel extends AbstractListModel implements MutableComboBoxModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Object selectedItem;
    private ArrayList<Object> sections;

    public SectionComboBoxModel(ArrayList<Object> arrayList) {
        sections = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedItem;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectedItem(Object newValue) {
        selectedItem = newValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return sections.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int i) {
        return sections.get(i);
    }

    public void setElementAt(Object newValue, int i) {
        this.fireContentsChanged(newValue, i, i);
        this.sections.set(i, newValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void addElement(Object obj) {
        sections.add(obj);
        this.fireIntervalAdded(obj, this.getSize() - 1, this.getSize() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeElement(Object obj) {
        this.fireIntervalRemoved(obj, sections.indexOf(obj), sections.indexOf(obj));
        sections.remove(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertElementAt(Object obj, int index) {
        sections.add(index, obj);
        this.fireIntervalAdded(obj, index, index);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeElementAt(int index) {
        this.fireIntervalRemoved(sections.get(index), index, index);
        sections.remove(index);

    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("\nPrinting List");
        for (int i = 0; i < this.sections.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(this.sections.get(i));
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return sections.contains(o);
    }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        return this.sections.toArray();
    }
}
```