# ComboBoxModel as wrapper for ListModel

Tags: java, swing, comboboxmodel

I want a `javax.swing.ListModel` be shared among multiple `javax.swing.ComboBoxModel`s.

With the following code , when I select an item from the `JComboBox`,in a running program through the view, the `JComboBox` always shows the first item as selected.

```
public class DelegatedComboBoxModel<T> extends AbstractListModel<T> implements
    ComboBoxModel<T> {

  protected ListModel<T> listModel;
  protected Object selectedObject;

  ListDataListener listDataChangeDelegater = new ListDataListener() {

    @Override
    public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent e) {
      fireIntervalRemoved(DelegatedComboBoxModel.this, e.getIndex0(),
          e.getIndex1());
    }

    @Override
    public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent e) {
      fireIntervalAdded(DelegatedComboBoxModel.this, e.getIndex0(),
          e.getIndex1());

    }

    @Override
    public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent e) {
      fireContentsChanged(DelegatedComboBoxModel.this, e.getIndex0(),
          e.getIndex1());
    }
  };

  public DelegatedComboBoxModel(ListModel<T> listModel) {
    // DefaultComboBoxModel<E>
    this.listModel = listModel;
    if (listModel.getSize() > 0) {
      selectedObject = listModel.getElementAt(0);
    }
    listModel.addListDataListener(listDataChangeDelegater);
  }

  @Override
  public T getElementAt(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < listModel.getSize())
      return listModel.getElementAt(index);
    else
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int getSize() {
    return listModel.getSize();
  }

  @Override
  public void setSelectedItem(Object anObject) {
    if ((selectedObject != null && !selectedObject.equals(anObject))
        || selectedObject == null && anObject != null) {
      selectedObject = anObject;
      fireContentsChanged(this, -1, -1);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Object getSelectedItem() {
    return selectedObject;
  }

}
```

I cannot figure out what went wrong with the above code.

How to fix the code ?

(Limitation : Should not use or subclass `DefaultComboBoxModel` or use any third-party library.)

Comment: did you search here for diff. variation of the AbstractListModel/MutableComboBoxModel

Comment: Sorrt. I cannot find any such variation of AbstractListMode/MutableComboBoxModel that uses the ListModel as the source of data.

Comment: for example [AbstractListModel](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+AbstractListModel) and [MutableComboBoxModel](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+MutableComboBoxModel) too lazy to search for code in SSCCE/MCVE form, search for arrays based on util.List only

Comment: [undeleted my post about both here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16294927/714968), and deleted post are accessible (view/undelete) for all users with reputation >10k

Comment: I would replace this large `if` condition with [`Objects.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)), but anyway, it doesn’t look wrong to me. When I try your code with `String` items, everything works fine. Do you have some custom item type with a broken `equals` implementation?

Comment: Yes the custom type has broken equals implementation. Thanks Holger and mKorbel.